# Multitenancy Hibernate SCHEMA approach, switching schema working with mysql but have questions

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, multi-tenant

All I have implemented multitenancy with `mysql` and `hibernate` but I have doubts that it will work in real world.

As per following quote from hibernate document it should be possible:

`Connections could point to the database itself (using some default schema) but the Connections would be altered using the SQL SET SCHEMA (or similar) command. Using this approach, we would have a single JDBC Connection pool for use to service all tenants, but before using the Connection it would be altered to reference the schema named by the “tenant identifier” associated with the currently logged in user.`

Here is the link from where I got above paragraph.

[Multitenancy in hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4754)

So I override the `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` as below

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
    Connection tenantSpecificConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(tenantIdentifier)) {
        Statement statement = tenantSpecificConnection.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery("use " + tenantIdentifier);
        statement.close();
        tenantSpecificConnection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier);
    } else {
        tenantSpecificConnection.setSchema(Constants.DEFAULT);
    }
    return tenantSpecificConnection;
}
```

It is very basic iteration, a first one, I am just able to switch the database. But with this I also have questions. Would this work in real world? I think multiple users will cause trouble while using this? According to hibernate documentation it should not but it looks it may cause problems. Has anyone tried this, please need help on this one.

Comment: "I think multiple users will cause trouble while using this?" Why do you think that?

Comment: Because multiple users will access the same code base simultaneously, all those users might belong to different tenants. and for each tenant I would be using different databse schema.

Comment: Yes, where's the trouble? You don't think that a single db connection is used by multiple users at the same exact time, do you? If you do, you should probably read a bit more about JDBC, databases, connection pooling etc. before you try to understand multi-tenancy. It seems you're trusting your own misinformed hunch more than the official documentation.

Comment: Ohhh yes, I got it now, it is changing the database for each connection. @Kayaman I got rusty a bit since long I haven't worked on JDBC/Hibernate stuff, but thanks :) :)

Comment: I will read about all those topics again :) :)

Comment: It changes the schema, not the database. If I remember correctly, Hibernate needs 2 separate config files (2 pools) to be able to connect to 2 databases.